# How to reset the "front end" to a 200% default

Tags: front-end, fonts

I wish that when Mathematica is run the "front end" this default to 200%, and perhaps other things where you can not change, as there are directly in the menu.

Thank You

Comment: Go to Edit->Preferences->Advanced, open Option Inspector, search for magnification, set to 2. Will not change the notebook tab - it stays at 100% (of your 2X magnification)...

Comment: I found it, I change, it changes and appears one two, put apply but an "x" as if I was wrong

Comment: depending on your operating system the "x" just means you have changed the default setting -- it does not mean an error has been made

Comment: As Mike said, this is just a handy indicator you've changed a default, so you can quickly find those and reset (manually, or just click the X) if desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can effect the setting for the evaluation Notebook with:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification :> 2. Inherited]
```

To create a new Notebook with this setting you can use:

```
CreateNotebook["Default", Magnification :> 2. Inherited]
```

This can easily be made into a [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) or Palette:

```
Button[
  "New 200% Notebook", 
  CreateNotebook["Default", Magnification :> 2. Inherited]
] // CreatePalette
```

Comment: thaks   both , perfect